# Error with array collection with a one to many relation

Tags: arrays, symfony, doctrine, entity

I have a problem with a OneToMany relation and "array collection" between my entity CV and my entities, Formation, Skills and Experiences. A CV can have several formation, experiences or skills.
Even with Symfony documentation, I'm not even sure to get the issues.
Here is my Skills entity (formation and experiences are the same)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\SkillsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SkillsRepository::class)
 */
class Skills
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Cv::class, inversedBy="id_skills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $id_cv;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function setType(string $type): self
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLevel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    public function setLevel(string $level): self
    {
        $this->level = $level;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCv(): ?Cv
    {
        return $this->id_cv;
    }

    public function setIdCv(?Cv $id_cv): self
    {
        $this->id_cv = $id_cv;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my CV entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CvRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CvRepository::class)
 */
class Cv
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Formation::class, mappedBy="id_cv", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $id_formation;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Experiences::class, mappedBy="id_cv", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $id_experiences;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Skills::class, mappedBy="id_cv", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $id_skills;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url_perso;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $video;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Candidate::class, mappedBy="id_cv", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $id_candidate;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id_formation = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->id_experiences = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->id_skills = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Formation[]
     */
    public function getIdFormation(): Collection
    {
        return $this->id_formation;
    }

    public function addIdFormation(Formation $id_cv): self
    {
        if (!$this->id_formation->contains($id_cv)) {
            $this->id_formation[] = $id_cv;
            $id_cv->setIdCv($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdFormation(Formation $id_cv): self
    {
        if ($this->id_formation->removeElement($id_cv)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($id_cv->getIdCv() === $this) {
                $id_cv->setIdCv(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Experiences[]
     */
    public function getIdExperiences(): Collection
    {
        return $this->id_experiences;
    }

    public function addIdExperience(Experiences $idExperience): self
    {
        if (!$this->id_experiences->contains($idExperience)) {
            $this->id_experiences[] = $idExperience;
            $idExperience->setIdCv($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdExperience(Experiences $idExperience): self
    {
        if ($this->id_experiences->removeElement($idExperience)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($idExperience->getIdCv() === $this) {
                $idExperience->setIdCv(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Skills[]
     */
    public function getIdSkills(): Collection
    {
        return $this->id_skills;
    }

    public function addIdSkill(Skills $idSkill): self
    {
        if (!$this->id_skills->contains($idSkill)) {
            $this->id_skills[] = $idSkill;
            $idSkill->setIdCv($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdSkill(Skills $idSkill): self
    {
        if ($this->id_skills->removeElement($idSkill)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($idSkill->getIdCv() === $this) {
                $idSkill->setIdCv(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUrlPerso(): ?string
    {
        return $this->url_perso;
    }

    public function setUrlPerso(string $url_perso): self
    {
        $this->url_perso = $url_perso;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVideo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->video;
    }

    public function setVideo(string $video): self
    {
        $this->video = $video;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdCandidate(): ?Candidate
    {
        return $this->id_candidate;
    }

    public function setIdCandidate(?Candidate $id_candidate): self
    {
        // unset the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($id_candidate === null && $this->id_candidate !== null) {
            $this->id_candidate->setIdCv(null);
        }

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($id_candidate !== null && $id_candidate->getIdCv() !== $this) {
            $id_candidate->setIdCv($this);
        }

        $this->id_candidate = $id_candidate;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In my CV entity, array collection and collection are underlined in red.I try to create my REST API.

When I do a post to create a CV, I have this error message:

> Could not denormalize object of type
> "Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection", no supporting
> normalizer found.

Do you have a clue about what's wrong?

Comment: So, whats the error? I mean, did you try to run it? What does de underlined error say?

Comment: actually i try to create API. and when i try to "Post" there is a probleme with serialization. So the request cant be done properly. I can not create CV

Comment: Sorry but i don't know exactly what's happening. Maybe these posts will help you. https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/309 https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2503